# Windows 7 fresh install blank screen

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, installation

I've just installed Win7 Ultimate to my PC. During the install it reboots a couple of times, but 2nd or 3rd reboot I see the "Starting Windows..." message, but followed by a black screen. No mouse cursor, taskbar, anything. The monitor power light is blue (indicating it has a signal) and it was displaying the setup wizard with no problems whatsoever.

Has anyone else witnessed this phenomenon?

Many thanks in advance.

### UPDATE

I booted in safe mode, and got a screen saying "Setup is preparing your computer for first use". That's brilliant, although a message box has popped up over that saying:

> Windows cannot complete instlalation in Safe Mode. To continue installing Windows, restart the computer.

So I don't really have the opportunity to do any cleverness with drivers or anything. I guess I could try getting a different version of Win7 (I'm installing from an MSDN DVD).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was just browsing the related questions on the right hand side, and found this:

[Windows 7 blank DVI screen](https://superuser.com/questions/55862/windows-7-blank-dvi-screen)

The answer was in there - I had two monitors hooked up, and when I disconnected the secondary one and rebooted, it all worked fine!

Comment: Yea, I've noticed that Win7 has some real issues with video, especially with older hardware.  When I upgraded my old HP laptop to Win7, it kept trying to install the wrong video driver, giving me the frequent black screen.  I finally was able to hack in the correct driver and it has worked great since.

Answer (score 1):

I have only seen this a few times, typically with hardware failure. (Windows setup loads a graphics driver for a faulty graphics card - SVGA/standard driver works, using the real driver fails).

All I can suggest is try booting in to safe mode and update all drivers, or perform another fresh install and cross your fingers!

Comment: +1 for the safe mode suggestion. It got me a bit further but not all the way (I've updated my question with my findings).

Comment: ok, with that updated info, I would start setup again, I think it simply failed.... Also, try looking at the setup log if you go to the command prompt during the next setup run.

Comment: Ahh right okay. I've done this twice now with the same results. What's the path/filename of the setup log? C:\setup.log?