# Windows 7 Safemode - Unable to load Powerstrip

Tags: windows-7, dvi, powerstrip

Hopefully I'm just missing something simple.

I have this [issue](https://superuser.com/questions/55862/windows-7-blank-dvi-screen).  So following the answer I purchased a licensed version of [Powerstrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm) and followed the instructions.

My problem is that when I load windows in safe mode, and I attempt to launch Powerstrip it does not get loaded into the system tray.  When I load windows normally, powerstrip appears in my system tray.

Am I missing something simple?  As I understand it, I need to load windows in safe mode to fix my DVI issue, however I also need to be able to have powerstrip loaded while in safe mode.

Thanks in advance.